# Windows 10 v 1709 (Fall Creators) waking randomly from hibernation

Tags: hibernate

I have three Dell Desktop PCs on Windows 10 v 1709, waking randomly from hibernation. The Windows 10 v 1703 was performing OK.  The solutions posted in Superuser were not effective.  When the Task Scheduler explorer tree was expanded and individually searched, I couldn't find a task in task scheduler with a "Wake computer" checkbox that was ticked.  A recent test of the suspected DmClientOnScenarioDownload had the file disabled but the PC still woke. I have three options:

The random wakes are from a noisy Ethernet; the Ethernet is receiving malicious magic packets; there is a task in Task Scheduler that is hidden.

Question: Are there hidden tasks in Task Scheduler that are capable of waking the computers? How can they be revealed? How should I disable them?
Thank you everybody.

Comment: `powercfg -lastwake` may provide some useful information. You can also look in the system event logs ...

Comment: Hello David.  Yes! I have been through all the usual remedies, including the Power Options.  Most work has been on Reboot in Update Orchestrator  and Task Scheduler.